# AngularJS plugin for intellij 15.0.1 not found

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

I am trying to install the AngularJS plugin for Intellij IDEA (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971?pr=idea), but am facing the following issues:

- when using the plugin browser, IDEA does not find it (only result is Ionic Framework when searching AngularJS)
- when downloading and installing manually, I get the following message: "Plugin AngularJS depends on unknown plugin JavaScript". A plugin I cannot, obviously, find.

Is this plugin no longer available for Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Are you using community version? I think it only supports Ultimate version

Comment: Yes you're right. Completely forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by Lawrence, this is not available for Community edition.